# Default activity not found android studio?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a problem that I have seen that a lot of other users have.
When I try to run my application I get an error that says that I have no default activity.
The weird thing is that in the first one everything works fine but on the second one it starts doing problems.
I've tried to do
    *"File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart..."*
but it works for only one run (sometimes doesn't work at all).
Also when I run the same code on another computer it works perfectly every time.
I tried reinstalling android studio but that did not help.

Comment: can you post your manifest here?

Comment: some new lines and formatting

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have at least one activity being the launcher in your manifest

```
<activity
    android:name="com.your.package.name.YourActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

if that does not work,go to files> Sync Project with gradle files